# API GET request fails with custom headers

Tags: python

I have this API GET request that works fine with the full address:

```
# Transactions
transaction_url = "https://api.whale-alert.io/v1/transaction/ethereum/0015286d8642f0e0553b7fefa1c168787ae71173cbf82ec2f2a1b2e0ffee72b2"
transaction_querystring = {
    "api_key":"APIKEY"
    }

transaction_response = requests.request("GET", transaction_url, params=transaction_querystring)
print(transaction_response)
print(transaction_response.text)
```

but, when I try to pass the variables as headers:

```
# Transactions
transaction_url = "https://api.whale-alert.io/v1/transaction"

transaction_querystring = {
    "api_key":"APIKEY"
    }
    
transaction_headers = {
    'blockchain': "ethereum",
    'hash': "0015286d8642f0e0553b7fefa1c168787ae71173cbf82ec2f2a1b2e0ffee72b2"
    }

transaction_response = requests.request("GET", transaction_url, headers=transaction_headers, data=transaction_querystring, )
print(transaction_response)
print(transaction_response.text)
```

It won't work:

> <Response [404]
>
> Not Found

Comment: passing as header is not same `/ethereum/0015286d8642f0e0553b7fefa1c168787ae71173cbf82ec2f2a1b2e0ffee72b2` is a specific route not header

Comment: @Epsi95 , you mean I have to create a unique route for every blockchain/hash I want to pull?

Comment: Why do you want to create the route? Did u read the API documentation? The route seems `https://api.whale-alert.io/v1/transaction/<crypo_currency_name>/<api_key>`

Comment: You have to check and follow what the API needs. If it requires passing the inputs as part of the URL, do that. If it requires passing the inputs in the headers, then do that. Passing it in the URL or in the headers are not the same. Your client app is not the one deciding how to pass the data. If you want to pass it in the headers and you control this API, then you have to modify the API to get the data from headers.

Comment: @Epsi95 , because I want to create a webapp that you select the blockchain you want from the dropdown menu, and it will add the hash from the database and return the result.

Comment: Then I would say your question lacks clarity, from your question it seemed that you are doing only http requests. Any way tou can implement but it depends on how `api.whale-alert.io` allows you to call their api

Comment: @Epsi95 , alright understood, thanks

Answer (score 0):

made it work with `{0}".format(startime_unix)`